# How do I store the result of an ajax call in a function using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, scope, anonymous-function

I have the folowing code:

```
function checkPermission(user) {
    var result = 'default';
    $.get('/mymodule/checkPermission.php?user=' + user, function(data) {
        result = data; // does not store data into result, why ?
        if (result == 'no') {
            $('.sorry_msg').show();
        }
    });
    alert(result); // shows "default".
    return result == 'yes';
}
```

Can you explain why this doesn't work. The problem is that **I cannot store the `data` variable into `result`**, see comments in the code. I guess <strike>it is because of the anonymous function</strike>, but I don't know javascript enough to understand exactly what happens.

Also, how can return `true` or `false` in `checkPermission` function based on the result of the ajax call ?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work - the Ajax call? The success callback? The check for `result`? Showing the HTML element? This needs basic debugging first

Comment: Anyway, `result` will not be present in the surrounding function due to the asychronous nature of Ajax.

Comment: I should also note that checking permission client-side seems like a really bad idea (unless it is purely cosmetic).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't get the expected result because the ajax callback function is executed asynchronously. This means that the process doesn't wait for the ajax call to finish. Therefor, before the ajax call has executed the callback function, the outer function `checkPermission` is already terminated and it's return value will therefor not have been altered by the ajax callback.

@pinouchon:
I've seen your suggested solution, but I would advise against using synchronous ajax requests, as this will block the whole user interface of the browser for the time it has to wait for the result of the ajax request. I'd suggest you rethink your execution strategy, and build it around asynchronously executed ajax requests.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery's `get()` method is an AJAX call, therefore Asynchronous with your method.  The function that is called at completion of the `get()` call, the one that changes the result value, executes AFTER your existing alert.  Try this:

```
$.get('/mymodule/checkPermission.php?user=' + user, function(data) {
    result = data; // does not store data into result.
    alert("Ajax Complete!"); // NEW ALERT CALL - called upon Ajax Completion
    if (result == 'no') {
        $('.sorry_msg').show();
    }
});
```

You'll see the order of the Alerts is "default" and then "Ajax Complete!"

The entire purpose of the callback function is to ensure that you are able to execute some code upon completion of the request.